# What do I do with an extra common wire attached to my GFCI?

Tags: electrical

I have a GFCI receptacle that has wires for line and load. There is also a hot red wire in the box that is wire nutted to a black wire for power somewhere and the common wire for that set up is combined with the common on the GFCI receptacle. I'm not understanding how that makes the path work. I have two bathroom recepticals that are not working that I think are connected to the load side of that particular GFCI.

Comment: Can you post pictures on how all the wires are connected?

Comment: There is no "common" in home wiring.  There's a "neutral" but it's specific to the hot wires being served and cannot serve any other circuit.  Your GFCI will teach you this :)

Comment: Do you mean the ground when you write "common"?

Comment: Are the two receptacles that are not working in the same bathroom or in different bathrooms? Does one GFCI receptcle provide protection for both bathrooms? In our house the two bathrooms are on one circuit, and it's a 15 A! Forty years ago I installed a GFCI receptacle in the upstream bathroom and supplied the other on the load terminals. It worked fine, but later I removed the GFCI receptacle and installed a GFCI breaker in the panel. This works, but I am not sure it's really a benefit.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: Yeah, the description is incomplete. We have an incoming cable with hot and neutral connected to GFCI line side. You mention some cabling connected on the GFCI Load side, which would protect some downstream receptacle of some form.  You then mention a red wire nutted to a black wire, and that it is paired with a neutral. Is this neutral from the line side of the GFCI, or the load side?  You mention this red wire is connected to a black wire, but don't mention where either goes.

Comment: For example, one possibility if the mystery connection's neutral is on the load side, would be that the load side of the outlet is connected to say a light switch via a three conductor cable (black, red, white, ground), where red is the the switched hot returning, with that then being connected to the black wire coming in from a lighting outlet.